# Chrome extension redirects every frame

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension

So I wrote a redirect script and unfortunately it redirects every single frame and I am new to java script and want to figure this simple extension out.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Flannel is #Winning ",
  "version": "0.2",
  "description": "Checks URL and redirects as required.",
  "background": { 
     "page":"bg.html"
     },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
     "js": ["content.js", "bg.js"]
   }
   ],
  "permissions": ["tabs","http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}
```

**bg.html**

```
<html>
<script src="redirect.js"></script>
</html>
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: newurl});
```

**redirect.js**

```
var url;
var newurl = "http://google.com/";
var newurl1 = "google.com/";

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    "use strict";
    url = tabs[0].url;
});


function myFunction(url) {
    "use strict";
    if (url !== newurl || url !== newurl1) {
        chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (request, sender) {
            chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
        });
    }
}

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
    "use strict";
    myFunction(tab.url);
});
```

unfortunately it refreshes every frame and I have tried to create a function that checks if the current URL is that one, and maybe it us just my inexperience in JavaScript but I wanted to challenge myself by writing my first chrome extension and I'm stumped. Any pointers or pointing to any sort of documentation to point me in the write direction would be appreciated.

**Update**

I've tried this and additional variations of it as well, it straight up hasn't redirected at all with this code injected in the content.js script

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
"use strict";
url = tabs[0].url;
myFunction(url);

});

function myFunction(url){
   if(url !== newurl){
       chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: newurl});
}
```

}

Comment: from what I can see, you're "injecting" content.js - `chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: newurl});` in every single page

Comment: @JaromandaX check out the update and give any adivce I dont know how to inject the page redirect only once.

Comment: Sorry Dan, I don't know enough about chrome extensions to help, I only made a comment (rather than an answer) because from the little I DO know about chrome extensions, it looks like you are injecting that piece of code in every page. If I was more experienced with chrome extensions, I'd have posted an **answer** rather than a comment

Comment: @JaromandaX No problem any help I always appreciate. Just thought I'd throw some more code in the mix anyways to show more confusion on the whole hey this looks like it should work, it doesn't, and there aren't any errors, the ultimate confusion errors.

Comment: Can you explain what your goal is? Redirect every page that isn't google.com? Because there's a way simpler way to do that than with all the different pieces you've got set up. Also,  "if (url !== newurl || url !== newurl1)" is always true. I think you mean &&, not ||

Comment: @KammyLiu yes I'm trying to redirect all pages to Google. That snippet with the function that I tried doesn't even redirect hence my confusion there. I just don't want it to redirect even when it's in the proper Web page which its doing.

Comment: make a content script instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by doing this in the content.js

```
if (window.location.href !== newurl) {
    window.location.href = newurl;
}
```

Thank you for all of your help everyone!

Comment: This is indeed a much simpler solution.